# How to add a line break after each sass extended class

Tags: sass, extend

with Sass,

```
%red-text { color: red; }

.text-1 { @extend %red-text; }
.text-2 { @extend %red-text; }
.text-3 { @extend %red-text; }
```

will render

```
.text-1, .text-2, text-3 { color: red; }
```

Is it possible to compile like so?

```
.text-1, 
.text-2,
.text-3 { color: red; }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check this following link, you can set your output style in Sass.

[SASS Refence - Output styles](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#output_style)

Comment: How does this help? The sass style does not affect the @extend output…